# Good manual on Assembly flags

Tags: assembly, flags, manual, instructions

What is a good Manual/Article on all of the Assembly flags and what instructions affect each flags?
Thanks!

Comment: Which cpu? x86: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register

Comment: Which instruction affects which flags, and how, is CPU- and instruction-specific, so you´ll find that info in the instruction set documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official one from Intel, of course!

[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Combined Volumes:1, 2A, 2B, 2C, 3A, 3B, and 3C](http://download.intel.com/products/processor/manual/325462.pdf).

For more see [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).

Comment: Oh Sorry! I meant for the 80x86 architecture, but thanks for the link! I'll look at the Intel manuals.
Thanks!

Comment: That's **the** architecture.